# C++ - Code Optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, data-structures

I have a problem:

> You are given a sequence, in the form of a string with characters ‘0’, ‘1’, and ‘?’ only. Suppose there are k ‘?’s. Then there are 2^k ways to replace each ‘?’ by a ‘0’ or a ‘1’, giving 2^k different 0-1 sequences (0-1 sequences are sequences with only zeroes and ones).
>
> For each 0-1 sequence, define its number of inversions as the minimum number of adjacent swaps required to sort the sequence in non-decreasing order. In this problem, the sequence is sorted in non-decreasing order precisely when all the zeroes occur before all the ones. For example, the sequence 11010 has 5 inversions. We can sort it by the following moves: 11010 →→ 11001 →→ 10101 →→ 01101 →→ 01011 →→ 00111.
>
> Find the sum of the number of inversions of the 2^k sequences, modulo 1000000007 (10^9+7).

For example:

> Input: ??01
> -> Output: 5
>
> Input: ?0?
> -> Output: 3

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;



void ProcessSequences(char *input)
{
int c = 0;

/* Count the number of '?' in input sequence
 * 1??0 -> 2
 */
for(int i=0;i<strlen(input);i++)
{
    if(*(input+i) == '?')
    {
        c++;
    }       
}


/* Get all possible combination of '?'
 * 1??0
 * -> ?? 
 * -> 00, 01, 10, 11
 */
int seqLength = pow(2,c);
// Initialize 2D array of integer
int **sequencelist, **allSequences;
sequencelist = new int*[seqLength];
allSequences = new int*[seqLength];
for(int i=0; i<seqLength; i++){
    sequencelist[i] = new int[c];
    allSequences[i] = new int[500000];
}
//end initialize

for(int count = 0; count < seqLength; count++)
{
    int n = 0;
    for(int offset = c-1; offset >= 0; offset--)
    {
        sequencelist[count][n] = ((count & (1 << offset)) >> offset);
        // cout << sequencelist[count][n];
        n++;
    }
    // cout << std::endl;
}   

/* Change '?' in former sequence into all possible bits
 * 1??0 
 * ?? -> 00, 01, 10, 11
 * -> 1000, 1010, 1100, 1110
 */
for(int d = 0; d<seqLength; d++)
{
    int seqCount = 0;
    for(int e = 0; e<strlen(input); e++)
    {
        if(*(input+e) == '1')
        {
            allSequences[d][e] = 1;
        }
        else if(*(input+e) == '0')
        {
            allSequences[d][e] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            allSequences[d][e] = sequencelist[d][seqCount];
            seqCount++;
        }
    }
}


/* 
 *  Sort each sequences to increasing mode
 * 
 */
// cout<<endl;
int totalNum[seqLength];
for(int i=0; i<seqLength; i++){
    int num = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<strlen(input); j++){
        if(j==strlen(input)-1){
            break;
        }
        if(allSequences[i][j] > allSequences[i][j+1]){
            int temp = allSequences[i][j];
            allSequences[i][j] = allSequences[i][j+1];
            allSequences[i][j+1] = temp;
            num++;
            j = -1;
        }//endif
    }//endfor
    totalNum[i] = num;
}//endfor





/*
 * Sum of all Num of Inversions
 */
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<seqLength;i++){
    sum = sum + totalNum[i];
}


// cout<<"Output: "<<endl;
int out = sum%1000000007;
cout<< out <<endl;


} //end of ProcessSequences method


int main()
{
   // Get Input
   char seq[500000];
   // cout << "Input: "<<endl;
   cin >> seq;

   char *p = &seq[0];

   ProcessSequences(p);
   return 0;
}
```

the results were right for small size input, but for bigger size input I got time CPU time limit > 1 second. I also got exceeded memory size. How to make it faster and optimal memory use? What algorithm should I use and what better data structure should I use?, Thank you.

Comment: You don't show your code in the question (so your question is very unclear). And if you did show your code, your question would become a *fix-my-code* question so is off-topic here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Updated, sorry, I forgot to post my code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , oh so there's a fix-my-code question, sorry didn't know about that.

Comment: This line "c++;" Justifies to flag it as c++ code;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic programming is the way to go. Imagine You are adding the last character to all sequences.

- If it is `1` then You get `XXXXXX1`. Number of swaps is obviously the same as it was for every sequence so far.
- If it is `0` then You need to know number of ones already in every sequence. Number of swaps would increase by the amount of ones for every sequence.
- If it is `?` You just add two previous cases together

You need to calculate how many sequences are there. For every length and for every number of ones (number of ones in the sequence can not be greater than length of the sequence, naturally). You start with length 1, which is trivial, and continue with longer. You can get really big numbers, so You should calculate modulo 1000000007 all the time. The program is not in C++, but should be easy to rewrite (array should be initialized to 0, int is 32bit, long in 64bit).

```
long Mod(long x)
{
    return x % 1000000007;
}

long Calc(string s)
{
    int len = s.Length;
    long[,] nums = new long[len + 1, len + 1];
    long sum = 0;
    nums[0, 0] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(s[i] == '?')
        {
            sum = Mod(sum * 2);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if (s[i] == '0' || s[i] == '?')
            {
                nums[i + 1, j] = Mod(nums[i + 1, j] + nums[i, j]);
                sum = Mod(sum + j * nums[i, j]);
            }

            if (s[i] == '1' || s[i] == '?')
            {
                nums[i + 1, j + 1] = nums[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

**Optimalization**

The code above is written to be as clear as possible and to show dynamic programming approach. You do not actually need array `[len+1, len+1]`. You calculate column `i+1` from column `i` and never go back, so two columns are enough - old and new. If You dig more into it, You find out that row `j` of new column depends only on row `j` and `j-1` of the old column. So You can go with one column if You actualize the values in the right direction (and do not overwrite values You would need).

The code above uses 64bit integers. You really need that only in `j * nums[i, j]`. The `nums` array contain numbers less than 1000000007 and 32bit integer is enough. Even 2*1000000007 can fit into 32bit signed int, we can make use of it.

We can optimize the code by nesting loop into conditions instead of conditions in the loop. Maybe it is even more natural approach, the only downside is repeating the code.

The % operator is, as every dividing, quite expensive. `j * nums[i, j]` is typically far smaller that capacity of 64bit integer, so we do not have to do modulo in every step. Just watch the actual value and apply when needed. The `Mod(nums[i + 1, j] + nums[i, j])` can also be optimized, as `nums[i + 1, j] + nums[i, j]` would always be smaller than 2*1000000007.

And finally the optimized code. I switched to C++, I realized there are differences what `int` and `long` means, so rather make it clear:

```
long CalcOpt(string s)
{
    long len = s.length();
    vector<long> nums(len + 1);
    long long sum = 0;
    nums[0] = 1;
    const long mod = 1000000007;

    for (long i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == '1')
        {
            for (long j = i + 1; j > 0; --j)
            {
                nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
            }
            nums[0] = 0;
        }
        else if (s[i] == '0')
        {
            for (long j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            {
                sum += (long long)j * nums[j];
                if (sum > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 2) { sum %= mod; }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sum *= 2;
            if (sum > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 2) { sum %= mod; }
            for (long j = i + 1; j > 0; --j)
            {
                sum += (long long)j * nums[j];
                if (sum > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 2) { sum %= mod; }
                long add = nums[j] + nums[j - 1];
                if (add >= mod) { add -= mod; }
                nums[j] = add;
            }
        }
    }

    return (long)(sum % mod);
}
```

**Simplification**

Time limit still exceeded? There is probably better way to do it. You can either

1. get back to the beginning and find out mathematically different way to calculate the result
2. or simplify actual solution using math

I went the second way. What we are doing in the loop is in fact convolution of two sequences, for example:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0,... and 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,...
0*0 + 0*1 + 0*2 + 1*3 + 4*4 + 6*5 + 4*6 + 1*7 + 0*8...= 80
```

The first sequence is symmetric and the second is linear. It this case, the sum of convolution can be calculated from sum of the first sequence which is = 16 (`numSum`) and number from second sequence corresponding to the center of the first sequence, which is 5 (`numMult`). `numSum*numMult = 16*5 = 80`. We replace the whole loop with one multiplication if we are able to update those numbers in each step, which fortulately seems the case.

If s[i] == '0' then numSum does not change and numMult does not change.

If s[i] == '1' then numSum does not change, only numMult increments by 1, as we shift the whole sequence by one position.

If s[i] == '?' we add original and shiftet sequence together. numSum is multiplied by 2 and numMult increments by 0.5.

The 0.5 means a bit problem, as it is not the whole number. But we know, that the result would be whole number. Fortunately in modular arithmetics in this case exists inversion of two (=1/2) as a whole number. It is h = (mod+1)/2. As a reminder, inversion of 2 is such a number, that h*2=1 modulo mod. Implementation wisely it is easier to multiply numMult by 2 and divide numSum by 2, but it is just a detail, we would need 0.5 anyway. The code:

```
long CalcOptSimpl(string s)
{
    long len = s.length();
    long long sum = 0;
    const long mod = 1000000007;
    long numSum = (mod + 1) / 2;
    long long numMult = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == '1')
        {
            numMult += 2;
        }
        else if (s[i] == '0')
        {
            sum += numSum * numMult;
            if (sum > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 4) { sum %= mod; }
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum * 2 + numSum * numMult;
            if (sum > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 4) { sum %= mod; }

            numSum = (numSum * 2) % mod;
            numMult++;
        }
    }

    return (long)(sum % mod);
}
```

I am pretty sure there exists some simple way to get this code, yet I am still unable to see it. But sometimes path is the goal :-)

Comment: but It got memory limit exceed, I'll try to use bigintegers.

Comment: The code is written to be (hopefully) easy to understand. You actually do not need array long[len + 1, len + 1], You need only long[2, len + 1]. You can index it like nums[(i + 1)%2, j].

Comment: I got indexoutofrange.

Comment: I added the optimized version, hope it helps.

Comment: The optimized one I got time limit exceeded

Comment: You seem quite constrained. I added yet another version.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence has N zeros with indexes `zero[0], zero[1], ... zero[N - 1]`, the number of inversions for it would be `(zero[0] + zero[1] + ... + zero[N - 1]) - (N - 1) * N / 2`. (you should be able to prove it)

For example, `11010` has two zeros with indexes 2 and 4, so the number of inversions would be `2 + 4 - 1 * 2 / 2 = 5`.

For all 2^k sequences, you can calculate the sum of two parts separately and then add them up.

1) The first part is `zero[0] + zero[1] + ... + zero[N - 1]`. Each `0` in the the given sequence contributes `index * 2^k` and each `?` contributes `index * 2^(k-1)`

2) The second part is `(N - 1) * N / 2`. You can calculate this using a dynamic programming (maybe you should google and learn this first). In short, use `f[i][j]` to present the number of sequence with `j` zeros using the first `i` characters of the given sequence.